# Probability of obtaining all four values in a roll of nine four-sided dice

Tags: probability, dice

I know that when calculating the probability of one result, e.g., getting at least one 4, you would use the equation -

$1-(3/4)^9$

But I'm not sure what kind of equation you would use to find out the probability of getting at least one of each.

By one of each value I mean a result that has at least one 1, at least one 2, at least one 3 and at least one 4.

For example, I'm looking for a result like, (1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)
Or (1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), etc...

Something that would not meet the criteria is (1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)

Comment: What do you mean by "one result of each value"? That terminology is rather vague.

Comment: "If I rolled 9 four-sided dice (d4), what is the chance that I would get one result of each value?"  Zero.  You are guaranteed to have duplicates.  Think about it.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer it doesn't seem vague to me. If the dice had values from $1-4$, OP is asking for the probability that rolling the dice leaves at least one on each of $1,2,3,4$

Comment: The question is confusing. Can you give an example of a roll which meets your criteria, and some examples of rolls which do not?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I'd expect $1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3$ wouldn't fit the criteria, but $1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4$ would.

Comment: @EricLippert sorry, typo. Added to comment above. The idea is that a success involves every number showing up at least once in the 9 rolls

Comment: @RhysHughes has got the right of it. Edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: @Rhys:  Your example $1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4$ seems not to get "one" result of each value:  you have *three* 1s, *three* 2s, etc.  I think the OP should clarify exactly what he's seeking.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: The goal is not to get exactly one of each result, but to get at least one of each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of reading your expression is that there are $4^9$ ordered ways for the dice to fall, of which $3^9$ have only $1,2,3$ showing, so the chance you get at least one $4$ is $\frac {4^9-3^9}{4^9}$.  You have subtracted the throws without a $4$ from all the throws.

It would seem then the chance you are not missing any number is $\frac {4^9-4\cdot 3^9}{4^9}$ because you have four choices of the number to be missing.  The problem is that you have subtracted rolls with two numbers missing twice and rolls with three numbers missing three times.  We add in the rolls with only two numbers, of which there are ${4 \choose 2}2^9$ but now we have added back the ones with only one number three times, so we need to subtract them once.  The final answer is 
$$\frac {4^9-{4 \choose 1}3^9+{4 \choose 2}2^9-{4\choose 3}1^9}{4^9}$$
This is an example of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: Thank you so much! It's all a bit over my head, I definitely need to study up a bit more on the subject. But this gives me a great place to start.